# Possible to customize font of prompt string in nav bar on IB?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

Is it possible to customize the prompt string at all?

I have hooked up the navigationBarItem to my ViewController and added a string as the "Prompt" via IB. There are no properties following the prompt class that allow me to alter the contents of the string, color, etc etc. I was wondering if anyone knows any other possible work around for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to customize the prompt appearance with one big limitation, the style of the prompt and of the title will always be the same.

Assuming you are in a `UIViewController` presented within a navigation controller with a navigation bar, you can do this:

```
guard let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17) else {
   return
}

let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
navigationBar?.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue]
```

You can also use the `UINavigationBar.appearance()` method to have this configuration on all the navigation bar prompts in your app.

Comment: it says that titleTextAttributes cannot be used on type UINavigationBar

Comment: Sorry, this was based on the code for the `appearance()` proxy. I edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: This is not working for me, promp's color and font did not change. Dead end?