# Change font of prompt in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

can someone help me out in changing font, size and color in prompt string on my NavigationController?

In the attachment, I want to modify "Consulenze" string.
Thank you everybody[image]

Edit: I already tried the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516831/possible-to-customize-font-of-prompt-string-in-nav-bar-on-ib) but no results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to customize font of prompt string in nav bar on IB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516831/possible-to-customize-font-of-prompt-string-in-nav-bar-on-ib)

Comment: I tried it, but with no results...better update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following ways:
1) In viewDidLoad of your ViewController add this lines:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

let navigationTitleFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 20)!

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: navigationTitleFont]
```

2) You can create completely custom nav bar, just add UIView to the top your view and add all necessary elements - buttons, labels, etc.

Comment: the first solution didn't give me positive results, so I created a fake nabber, which is not what I meant to do. thanks anyway, still waiting for an answer to my question though.

Comment: Could you show code, how you create navigationBar, or show screenshot from InterfaceBuilder
And could you provide image with navBar how you want it has to look like?
Now you provided actual image of navBar or how you want it has to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this code in your `ViewController`. You can change both the `Prompt text` and `color` by using this code -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        for view in self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews ?? [] {
            let subviews = view.subviews
            if subviews.count > 0, let label = subviews[0] as? UILabel {
                label.textColor = UIColor.red
                label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT -**

[image]

**Additional -**

**[image: Additional -]**

Comment: Did you add those in your appdelegate file?. I think you are not putting it in right place. you can see this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO8_mqRJO-4&t=203s

Comment: I don’t think you have understood what I asked: that’s not the title of the navbar, but the prompt string.

Comment: i understand. The link is for only where you can put your customized code :)

Comment: Ok then. But you were clear enough in your answer, and I put the code right in the did finish launching with options, but the code you suggested me changes the title, not the prompt.

Comment: If you provide me any sample code then it will be easier for me to understand.

Comment: But there’s no code to post. I just set the prompt title via storyboard, and have no idea how to change the font, size and color of prompt title, so I asked here and that’s it XD. I tried every solution in this answer and in the other one. In your case: I tried the first one, putting those three lines of code in did finish launching with options, but with no effects; the second one I put the barTintColor and the tintColor in the viewDidLoad of the controller first and in did finish launching then, and didn’t worked (how could that be anyway? That’s just for changing the colors);

Comment: the last one I put the appearance() code in both view did load first and appdelegate then, no results.

Comment: Then we are close to solve this. You should include this in your question. You can change the color from your xcode. Just click on the text and go to your attribute inspector on the right side of xcode. there you can find the oprion to change that text color. let me know..if you face any difficulties .

Comment: Ok now I have the certain that you didn’t understand my question :D please check yourself, open a project, embedding a view controller in a navigation controller, click on the navbar in your VC, attributes inspector and there you go, write something on “prompt” and see what happens. THAT string I want to modify.